# Scrape using Beautiful Soup preserving &nbsp; entities

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing, html-entities

I would like to scrape a table from the web and keep the &nbsp; entities intact so that I can republish as HTML later.  BeautifulSoup seems to be converting these to spaces though.  Example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = "<html><body><table><tr>"
html += "<td>&nbsp;hello&nbsp;</td>"
html += "</tr></table></body></html>"

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
table = soup.find_all('table')[0]
row = table.find_all('tr')[0]
cell = row.find_all('td')[0]

print cell
```

observed result:

```
<td> hello </td>
```

required result:

```
<td>&nbsp;hello&nbsp;</td>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In bs4 `convertEntities` parameter to BeautifulSoup constructor is not supported anymore. HTML entities are always converted into the corresponding Unicode characters (see [docs](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#entities)).

According to docs, you need to use an output formatter, like this:

```
print soup.find_all('td')[0].prettify(formatter="html")
```